# "For" loop than overwrites when using write.table

Tags: arrays, r, loops, filenames, overwrite

I am trying to extract every two consecutive columns from an array, writing a .dat with every pair. The problem is that, when using write.table() it overwrites the files. When I use print() instead of write.table() it shows the correct subsets, though.

I also need the file names to show the number of the pair of columns selected (a total of 6 pairs), as well as the number of the dimension (from 1 to 5). For this I have used an easier solution such as tagging 1:30.

```
for(i in 0:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    for (k in 1:30) {
      filename <- paste("Component",k, ".dat", sep="")
      write.table(data[,c(2*i+1,2*i+2),j],col.names=F, row.names=F, sep= " ")    
    } 
  }
}
```

Any hints why it does not work?
I hope my goal is understandable. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Well, have you tried passing `filename` to `write.table`? The filename should probably also contain `i` and `j`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I simplified the code here and forgot to include it, but I had typed it in my R code with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the argument [`append`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) to `TRUE`:

```
write.table(data[,c(2*i+1,2*i+2),j], 
            file=filename, 
            append=TRUE,
            col.names=F, 
            row.names=F, 
            sep= " ")
```

also, as correctly pointed out by @Roland, you have forgotten to pass the file argument (already added in my example above).

Comment: There is still an error. I copy here my commands and the R message:   `for(i in 0:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
      filename <- paste("Component",c(j,i+1),".dat", sep="")
      write.table(data[,c(2*i+1,2*i+2),j], filename, append=T, col.names=F, row.names=F, sep= " ")    
   }
}
`   The error reads::   `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`   Thanks for your help!

Comment: `filename <- paste("Component",c(j,i+1),".dat", sep="")` produces a vector with 2 file names (write.table accepts one), you probably want to do this: `filename <- paste("Component", j, "_", i+1, ".dat", sep="")`